MySQL 8 - returning more than one row for the one given ID
I try to understand the following problem. I have a table, let it be A, where ID field is varbinary(50).
Then trying to select from this table:
select id from A where id in (9044923298344967);
This clearly should give me one unique records, but I'm getting 3 records instead:
[ { "id": "9044923298344967" }, { "id": "9044923298344968" }, { "id": "9044923298344969" } ].
Those are of course unique records, not only ID but all other data differs.
It works as expected when I modify my query and pass ID as a string:
select id from A where id in ("9044923298344967");
[ { "id": "9044923298344967" } ]
In fact the problem is solved. But I would like to understand what happen here, so I know what impact it could have in other place of the application.

I assume because VARBINARY stores bytes, no characters, so when comparing bytes, maybe some types conversion are made and it overflows values

Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation

On your first query, you don't use binary but integer, if you want to use binary, you should cast like this:
id IN (CAST(9044923298344967 AS BINARY));

^ More specifically, why not use a primary key that is an Integer that Auto Increments, so that there are unique values for every record automatically.

When you compare a string against an integer, the values are converted to DOUBLE first before comparing them. This behavior is defined in 14.3 Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation:

[...]

In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (double-precision) numbers. For example, a comparison of string and numeric operands takes place as a comparison of floating-point numbers.


When converting a string/integer to a floating-point number you might loose accuracy. This can affect the comparison of such values. See the following example:
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Example(Value VARCHAR(50));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Example(Value) VALUES ("9044923298344966"),
                                         ("9044923298344967"),
                                         ("9044923298344968"),
                                         ("9044923298344969"),
                                         ("9044923298344970");
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT Value, CAST(Value AS DOUBLE), CAST(9044923298344967 AS DOUBLE) FROM Example;
+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| Value            | CAST(Value AS DOUBLE) | CAST(9044923298344967 AS DOUBLE) |
+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
| 9044923298344966 |  9.044923298344966e15 |             9.044923298344968e15 |
| 9044923298344967 |  9.044923298344968e15 |             9.044923298344968e15 |
| 9044923298344968 |  9.044923298344968e15 |             9.044923298344968e15 |
| 9044923298344969 |  9.044923298344968e15 |             9.044923298344968e15 |
| 9044923298344970 |   9.04492329834497e15 |             9.044923298344968e15 |
+------------------+-----------------------+----------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

As you see, the string values ending in "..67", "..68" and "..69" are all cast to the same DOUBLE value, as well as the integer value 9044923298344967. This means that these values are "equal" in this context, but not the other "close" strings ending in "..66" and "..70".
